# web table handling selenium webdriver java

Tags: selenium

```
     <table class="footable table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" 
     cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" border="0">
     <thead>
     <tr class="CartBlueHeader">
     <th align="10%">PNR No</th>
     <th width="23%" align="center">Origin</th>
     <th width="22%" align="center">Destination</th>
     <th width="10%">Departure</th>
     <th width="10%">Return</th>
     <th width="10%">Amount</th>
     <th width="15%"/>
     </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="BGLightblue font11">
       <td align="left">   Q2S2SO </td>
       <td align="left">   Dubai Intl Airport </td>
       <td align="left">   Hindustan Airport </td>
       <td align="center"> 30 Sep 17 </td>
       <td align="center">-</td>
       <td align="left"> 608.00 SAR   </td>
       <td align="left">
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Want to retrieve the values elements based on its header value in the table. How do i proceed with this any idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I mean i need to print the values of td based on its th value.

Comment: post your code what your tried

Comment: Create a class which takes input as a `row (tr)` element and then map each `td` to it's variable created as per header.

Answer (score 0):

> Follow the pattern only

```
// Grab the table 
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("divListView")); 

// Now get all the TR elements from the table 
List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 

// And iterate over them, getting the cells 
for (WebElement row : allRows) { 
    List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 

    // Print the contents of each cell
    for (WebElement cell : cells) { 
        System.out.println(cell.getText());
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: can we do something with the List

Comment: you have to grab data within a loop

Comment: List<WebElement> header=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main-mid-area']/div/div/form/table/thead/tr/th"));

Comment: the above list consists of all headers

Comment: List<WebElement> values=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main-mid-area']/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td"));                 This list consists of all the values with respect to  its header values

Answer (score 0):

A Table class:

```
public Table {

  private WebDriver driver;

  private By baseLocator;
  private By headCellLocator;
  private By bodyRowLocator;
  private By bodyCellLocator;

  private String[] headColumns;
  private List<WebElement> findRows;

  public Tabele(WebDriver, driver, By baseLocator) {
    this.driver = driver;
    this.baseLocator = baseLocator;
  }

  public Table init(headCellLocator, bodyRowLocator, bodyCellLocator) {
    this.headCellLocator = headCellLocator;
    this.bodyRowLocator = bodyRowLocator;
    this.bodyCellLocator = bodyCellLocator;

    this.readHeadColumns();

    return this;
  }

  private readHeadColumns() {
    List<WebElement> headCells = this.driver
        .findElement(this.baseLocator)
        .findElements(this.headCellLocator);

    for(WebElement headCell:headCells) {
        ArrayUtils.add(this.headColumns, headCell.getText().trim())
    }
  }

  public Table findRows() {
        this.findRows = this.driver
            .findElement(this.baseLocator)
            .findElements(this.bodyRowLocator);

        return this;
  }

  public Table findRows(String columnName, String columnValue) {

    int columnIndex = ArrayUtils.indexOf(this.headColumns, columnName);

    findRows();

    List<WebElement> matchRows = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

    for(WebElement row:findRows) {
            String cellText = row.findElements(this.bodyCellLocator)
                .get(columnIndex)
                .getText()
                .trim();

            if(cellText.equals(columnValue)) {
                matchRows.add(row);
            }
    }

    this.findRows = matchRows;

    return this;
  }

  public String[] readColumnValue(String columnName) {

    int columnIndex = ArrayUtils.indexOf(this.headColumns, columnName);
        String[] columnValue;
        String cellText;

    for(WebElement row: findRows) {
        cellText = String cellText = row.findElements(this.bodyCellLocator)
                .get(columnIndex)
                .getText()
                .trim();

        ArrayUtils.add(columnValue, cellText);
    }

    return columnValue;
  }
}

Table table = new Table(By.cssLocator('body .footable'));

table.init(By.cssLocator('thead th'), By.cssLocator('tbody > tr'), By.cssLocator('td'));

table.findRows().readColumnValue('PNR No');

// or
table.findRows('Origin', 'Dubai Intl Airport').readColumnValue('PNR No');
```

Answer (score 0):

The TableDriver extension to WebDriver (https://github.com/jkindwall/TableDriver.Java) allows you to identify a table's contents by contextual information.  For example, given the above table, if you wanted to find the "Departure" value for a particular "PNR No", you could do something like this.

```java
Table table = Table.create(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.footable.table")));
String departure = table.findCell("PNR No=   Q2S2SO ", "Departure").getElement().getText();
```