# How can I search a value in a table and then get the other cell value on the same row?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to write a generic method, which I can do a search on a table to locate a specific row. Then, I can get the other values on the same row.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Amazon</td>
      <td>$100.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Samsung</td>
      <td>$200.00</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

For example, I pass amazon to the method. The method will locate the row contains Amazon. And, it will get the value = $100.00 on the same row.

How can i do it using Selenium Java? Thanks

Comment: A generic Table class if you interested:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404136/web-table-handling-selenium-webdriver-java/46404926#46404926

Answer (score 0):

The following method may be help you.

```
public String find(WebDriver driver, String searchString){
    List<WebElemet> lstElements=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tr/td");
       for(int i=0;i<lstElements.size();i++){
         if(lstElements.get(i).getText().equals(searchString)){
           return lstElments(i+1).getText();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get your value from table pass amazon into str then you will get respective value as $100.00

```
   public String getValue(String str){
                        String xpath = "//td[text()='%s']";
                          String ele= String.format(xpath,str);
                            WebElement productname= driver.findElement(By.xpath(ele));
               return productname.findElement(By.xpath("/following-sibling::td")).getText(); 
    }
```